# Count total number of repetitions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Consider the integers $\{1,2,...,K\}$ with $K\geq 2$.

List all possible ways to dispose these integers in $T\geq 2$ spaces s.t.

- repetitions are allowed
- order does not matter
- $T$ may be greater, equal, or smaller than $K$.

As answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4159048/count-number-of-ways-to-dispose-list-of-integers), there are $\binom{K+T-1}{K-1}$ possible ways. For example:

- if $K=2$ and $T=2$, we have $3$ ways: $\{1,1\}, \{1,2\}, \{2,2\}$
- if $K=2$ and $T=3$, we have $4$ ways: $\{1,1,1\}, \{1,1,2\}, \{1,2,2\}, \{2,2,2\}$
- if $K=3$ and $T=2$, we have $6$ ways: $\{1,1\}, \{2,2\}, \{3,3\}, \{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{2,3\}$

For each of these possible ways, I want to find a "compact" way to represent the total number of repetitions of "1", total number of repetitions of "2", ..., total number of repetitions of "$K$".

For example, let us continue with $K=2$ and $T=3$:

\begin{array}{c c c| c|c|}
  &   &  & \text{How many 1} & \text{How many 2}\\
\hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 0 \\
\hline
1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 1\\
\hline
1 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 2\\
\hline
2 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 3\\
\end{array}

Then, the last two columns can be "compactly" represented as follows:
$$
\{(A_1, A_2)\in \{0,1,2,3\}^2 \text{ s.t. } A_1+A_2=3\}
$$

How can I generalise this to any $K,T$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your representation, you can generalise it this way:

$$\{(A_1, \dots,A_K)\in [|0,T|]^K \text{ s.t. } \sum_{i=1}^K A_i=T\}$$